# Advanced VS2012 Find and Replace with regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012, replace

In VS2012 I am wanting to find and replace a "near-repetitive" string within a few large generated .SQL files:

The format of the search string is:

```
print 'Processed {d} total records'
```

where {d} is a number such as 100, 200, 300 etc all the way up to 70,000

I will be replacing this will nothing (i.e. deleting it)

Can anybody provide me with a simple regex for the FIND using the new [VS2012 syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2k3te2cs.aspx)?

Regex is like witchcraft and is beyond me

Any questions feel free to ask

Cheers

Kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
print 'Processed [0-9]+ total records'
```

If your number contains thousands separators (like in '70,000') you might want to use

```
print 'Processed [0-9,]+ total records'
```

instead.

`[]` is a bracket expression which matches any of the characters inside it, so `[0-9]` matches every digit (since `0-9` is a character range). The `+` in the end means 'any number of matches but at least one'.

Comment: it worked like a charm. FYI the generated files didnt have , in it :-)